# How can I run spark jobs in order?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am submitting multiple Spark jobs.
One job uses one worker.
Currently I have 30 jobs submitted at once, 5 job are run and 25 job are waiting.
However, this operation puts a heavy load on the server. (Sometimes the job port cannot be assigned and an error occurs.)

Is it possible to reduce the load while running 5 pieces at a time?

Currently my running code::

```
~/spark-submit ~test1.py & ~/spark-submit ~test2.py & ~/spark-submit ~testN.py & ... ~/spark-submit ~test30.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe with and "&" you are using all of them at the same time.

If you put ";" instead of "&" and they will not be executed at once, but wait for it to finish.

```
~/spark-submit ~test1.py ; ~/spark-submit ~test2.py ; ~/spark-submit ~testN.py ; 
~/spark-submit ~test30.py;
```

You can also combine them and execute n of them in parallel like:

```
~/spark-submit ~test1.py & ~/spark-submit ~test2.py ; ~/spark-submit ~testN.py & 
~/spark-submit ~test30.py;
```

However, this is not the best approach, but rather a quick fix.
The reason is that some jobs will take longer than others and it will take more time for them to complete.
One solution would be to write a python script where you specify a pool of jobs and run 5 of them at once. Once one of them is finished you replace it with another one from the pool.

Comment: For example, what should I do? Can you see the example code?